# How to save an assembled NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, automatic-ref-counting

sometimes I have to "load" an array under some conditions.
So I have a for loop and add the object to a temporary NSMutableArray.

But what is the best thing to do when my assembling process is done and I just need a static array in a property?

- Should I just set my temporary for the NSArray property?
- Should I use NSMutableArray's copy method and copy it to the property?
- Should I use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray]`?
- Should I use `[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray]` and is there a difference to `init`?

What is the best way (for performance and memory) to continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, so the simplest thing to do is assign your mutable array to a (non-mutable) `NSArray*` variable.  However, due to Objective-C's runtime dynamism, if your code is not well-formed, you could end up accidentally mutating this array that is expected to be static.  If you create a non-mutable copy of the array, any such accidental call will result in the program crashing.

`NSMutableArray`'s `-copy` method should return a mutable copy, so I think this is not what you want to do.  The last two options you wrote are equivalent under ARC's optimizations; the difference is that `+arrayWithArray:` returns an autoreleased object, whereas `-initWithArray:` returns a retained object.

Here's an example of the difference, if you accidentally call an `NSMutableArray` method such as `-removeAllObjects`:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:n];
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    // add object to tempArray
    [tempArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:n];
}

// option 1:
[self setArray:tempArray];
[[self array] removeAllObjects]; // succeeds (that's bad)

// option 2:
[self setArray:[tempArray copy]];
[[self array] removeAllObjects]; // succeeds (that's bad)

// option 3:
NSArray *immutableArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArray];
[self setArray:immutableArray];
[[self array] removeAllObjects]; // fails (that's good)
// if not ARC: [immutableArray release];

// option 4:
NSArray *immutableArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
[self setArray:immutableArray];
[[self array] removeAllObjects]; // fails (that's good)
```

Answer (score 3):

It is generally a good idea for NSArray properties to be `copy` properties. So in most cases, you would just do `self.myProperty = temporaryArray`. It is usually best to let accessors take care of memory management concerns like this for you so that the responsibility is concentrated in a small area.

Answer (score 0):

There is not too much difference between all of those solution in terms of performance - however I will advice to use last one since it's cleanest:

```
[NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray]
```

The difference between this and init is that this one return autorelease object and init return +1 retain count object (you have to release it to dealloc it).

Same when you use [ copy] - than you need to release this object as well. Of course if you're using ARC you don't have to worry about this too much.

In terms of performance and keeping it as a property - if you can reuse constructed array keep it in property after you've done it once and there is a chance to reuse results. If you have to reconstruct it each time use local variable.